# How to set type of parameter in linq to nhibernate query for char(*) type?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate, profiler

I have a column for Code in Person table by char(4) type.

Person table is :

[image]

Person Hbm is :

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Domain" namespace="Domain.Model">      
  <class name="Person" table="Person">    

     <property name="Code" >      
        <column name="Code" **sql-type="char(4)"**/>    
     </property>

     ...

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now I have a linq to nhibernate query :

```
SessionInstance.Query<Person>()
               .Where(x => x.Code == "1234")
               .Select(x => x.Code)
               .ToList();
```

But trace of query in sql profiler is not expected.

```
exec sp_executesql N'select person_.Code as col_0_0_ from Person person_ where person_.Code=@p0',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'1234'
```

Because type of `@p0` is not `char(4)` and value of `@p0` is `N'1234'` instead of `'1234'`

And performance of this query is lower :
[image]

What's the cause?

Answer (score 0):

You should be totally fine leaving out the explicit type declaration. Usually the only scenarios where you would need to define the data type are where NHibernate does not default to the data type you're intending to use (common with some variants of date/time data types).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation in NHibernate 4.0:
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3403